# Limit Geocoder getFromLocationName scope to one specific City

Tags: android

The following is my method:

```
List<Address> addresses = null;
    addresses = new Geocoder(passengerHomeActivity).getFromLocationName(this.addressInput.getText().toString(), 1);
```

is there any way to limit the `Geocoder` `getFromLocationName`'s scope to one specific city? Sometimes when I enter an Address without writing the city name, it leads me to an address which is the same but in another city.

My idea is by getting the `latitude` and `longitude` of the user, get the value of the city, and set the limit scope to the `getFromLocationName` method, but I don't have any clue with the implementation.

Thanks

Comment: Hello hectichavana, did you find the answer? I have same issue.

Comment: Yes I found a workaround, get the user current location with Geopoint, get the city name, get it as a string and put it into the search query. So the search query will be "editText.getString() + user current city"

Comment: and if the user types the city along with the search query? your query would have the city name twice. Wouldn't it be better to filter the results?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
List<Address> addresses = new Geocoder(passengerHomeActivity).getFromLocationName((this.addressInput.getText().toString()) + ", YourCity, YourCountry", 1);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the constructor passing the the Locale.

```
Geocoder(Context context, Locale locale)
```

Use it like this:

```
Locale locale = new Locale(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage(), "US");
Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(context, locale)
addresses = geo.getFromLocationName(term, 1);
```

Notice that this is an aproach, because it will give you the result in that country unless nothing is found (in which case will return worldwide anyway).